# Android - running background task and handle activity restart

Tags: android, sdk, android-asynctask, intentservice

I am trying to work out the best approach to run a background task while showing a spinner dialog box and handle changes such as rotation of the device or if the device goes into a screen lock and then unlock state.

Currently my app has to work with API 8 up to 16 so I know that the getLastNonConfigurationInstance() is now redundant from api 11 (I think) up and I tried this method to make sure that it would not work on an API 8 device which it didn't. I then read about asynctaskloader but this is not available for API 8.

Finally I read about intentservice which appears could be the answer but I just need to know how to handle this with config changes where the activity is restarted.

My background tasks are either to loop through a sqlite database and export the rows as a CSV or to import from a CSV. These I have done already through an AsyncTask but if I rotate the device or lock the screen , they crash.

As the Activity is restarted I suspect that if I used a intentservice it would need to know the new activity "reference" so to speak. With an AsyncTask my understanding is that it is attached to the activity that started it so when it is re-created it looses that link.

***EDIT*****

Since my original question Marcin has helped out with some of the issues I have had. However it appears that the link to an example of an activity to a fragment does not match up to the source code that can be downloaded and so my question is as follows now :

I am trying to work out how to implement a fragment within my listactivity. I know that there is a Listfragment but if I change my listactivity to this, I will not be able to start the listfragment from an activity as I have tried this already and reading posts here this cannot be done unless the listfragment is inside an activity or fragment activity.

My reason for a fragment is to control configuration changes and the listactivity is used to display a list of files and folders , then the user can select the file they want to use , click import and then I need to start the fragment which will have the asynctask to import the data.

I have yet to find an example of a listactivity with a fragment that shows this and I am trying to figure this out.

Please ket me know if you require any code from my project

Thanks

TimCS

Comment: Do you want your activity to restart when the device rotates? You can choose not to restart it, if I am not wrong.

Comment: If that is possible, yes currently it restarts as normal when the screen is rotated or if the device goes to "sleep" and when unlocking the screen this sometimes causes it to crash so I an only assume that the activity (which is actually a ListActivity) must restart then as well. If you can let me know how to stop it restarting that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [setRerainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29). You can put AsyncTask in it and it wont be recreated after 
configuration changes. You can also read [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) post, it can be helpful

```
package com.example.we.helpers;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.example.we.MainActivity;

public class ImageFragment extends Fragment{
    public static final String URL = "http://link.com";
    private ImageTask task;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void startDownloading(){
        task = new ImageTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    public class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Bitmap bmp =null;
            try{
                URL ulr = new URL(URL);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulr.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bmp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if(getActivity() instanceof MainActivity == false){
                return;
            }

            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            activity.onImageLoaded(result);
        }


    }
}
```

This is how I run Fragment:

```
ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(fragment, LOADER);
transaction.commit();
fragment.startDownloading();
```

And here are imports from MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Comment: Thanks Macrin I will look at this. I thought that setRetainInstance needed to be used with a Fragment method or with getLastNonConfigurationInstance() - Yes it is used with a fragment and this is something I just cannot get my head around at the moment. Still I will try and push this into my brain. I also through t fragments were not around in API 8

Comment: @TimCS, yes it is used with Fragments. But with Support Library it is available before API 8.

Comment: @Macrin would an Intentservice be any better or would this be more complicated to manage ? Fragments look complicated to me over asyncTasks however looks like its time to get my teeth into them.

Comment: I dont know. Everything has it's good and bad sides. Fragments are not so complicated and for me it's better approach.

Comment: Thanks Marcin will try these out

Comment: Hi again Marcin, I have tried to use the example from the link you provided but I am hitting problems when trying to use the getFragmentManager method and I am wondering if this is because I am using it with the android.v4.app.Fragment library. I have also tried to start using this example (http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/) but I am trying to get my head around starting this from an activity which does not need to know the result when the async has finished as the fragment starts it.

Comment: @TimCS take a look at [getSupportFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()).

Comment: Also from reading this linked page the bit not covered in detail is in the activity where stated todo regain saved state , not quite sure how that ties in with the fragment

Comment: It appears not to want to use the getSupportFragmentManager and instead did this : android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); then the next line is erroring with cannot cast from fragment to TaskFragment and the line is as :  mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("task"); Also I am getting errors all over the TaskFragment Class as the code from the link I do not think is complete

Comment: I have since had some help with this so I will see how I get on

Comment: @TimCS I think, if you are using FragmentManager from SupportPackage you have to use getSupportFragmentManager. Also check if you have Fragment from correct import(supportPackage). If you are sure it's correct paste more code, please.

Comment: thanks for your reply because I didnt see from the link you gave me a download of the entire code from that page most of the code was missing plus as you have mentioned so will be the required import statements for backward compatibility. I will be looking at all of this tonight. One part I have got to work out is passing values from the activity to the fragment

Comment: very helpful, just had a first day back after a week off so my brain is buzzing at the moment. I am trying to get my head to concentrate on your hard work here for me and so I will be determined to do this even if it hurts me :)

Comment: Marcin - > Looking at your code I see you have used transaction.add(fragment, LOADER); is this how you have passed data to the fragment and if so how do you then retrieve this when in the fragment class itself ? I cannot seem to see a reference to this

Comment: It's just adding fragment to the activity. I'm not passing any data to fragment. Create some function in your fragment class if you want to pass data.

Comment: Having problems now as I am trying to change my ListActivity to a ListFragment but this does not allow for the setContentView method in onCreate whereas if I extend FragmentActivity it does. The way the activity is currently coded needs it to be a ListActivity/ListFragment how do I get around this please?

Comment: If you use ListFragment(Fragments at all) you have to overload onCreateView instead of simply calling setContentView.

Comment: Macrin yes I have started with that now thanks suddenly struck me after a while . However I am getting an error when trying to start the Listfragment from an Activity even after reading posts here how to do this and to add the ListFragment to the Android Manifest. If I cannot sort it I may post it here or should I create a new post?

Comment: Create new post maybe becouse this is pretty long I think.

Comment: Marcin from the original link you kindly provided it appears that from the author, the actual source code you can download, does not represent the code on on the page. I am editing my question in conjunction with my goal so I would appreciate any help on this matter

Comment: Marcin thanks again for your edit, I seem to have figured out how to passed data from the activity to the fragment, my question now is how can I pass data back from the asyncTask/Fragment when the background process has finished? basically the activity will prompt the user to continue - Replying Yes will start the fragment/asyncTask, when finished it will display another dialog stating how many records imported and ask the user if they want to quit to the main program or stay in the current activity

Comment: I am sure however I did try and start a fragment from an activity using the begintransaction etc and it would not take it but I will try again the way you have shown here as I was using the way that was from your link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35429/discussion-between-timcs-and-marcin-gawel)